# Layer size in gensim's word2vec

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, gensim, word2vec

When I start training my word2vec model, I am presented with the warning

> consider setting layer size to a multiple of 4 for greater performance

That sounds neat, but I can't find any reference to a `layer` argument or similar in [the documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec).

So how can I increase the layer size, and how can I determine a good value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The layer size simply means the size (dimension) of the word vectors which can be set with the `size` parameter. The default value is 100 but you can for example try with 128 to have a multiple of 4. The best size depends on your training data and has to be determined empirically. In general, more data means that you can go for a bigger size.